# Best Practice : Error Handling in Promise in async method

Tags: typescript, async-await, angular-promise, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

I am using typescript and used promises to maintain synchronous behavior in my code .As per my research though we have try catch bloc around promise we are getting un-handled exception when something goes wrong in our promise

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): false

to overcome this issue I have added catch bloc to my promise as below. However I am not confident about best practice of this usage. If anyone can share advice on this it would be very helpful.

```
async testMethod(pram1 : pramType): Promise<boolean>{
    try{
        return await this.promisemethod(pram1).catch(function () {
                                                tl.debug("Promise Rejected");
                                                return false;});

    }catch () {
        tl.debug("Method Failed");
    }   

}
```

Comment: How comes it's AngularJS question? There's no mention of it. I guess it should have typescript and ecmascript-2017 tags instead. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue, since it's unclear how you get this error. `.catch` is out of place here, but it should be handled with catch statement any way.

Comment: You do not need both `.catch()` and `try`/`catch`.